# Unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'? AurioTouch

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

I'm trying to move code from the AurioTouch project to my project.
But I have many errors:

```
Unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'?
```

For example, in file FFTBufferManager.h:

```
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#include <libkern/OSAtomic.h>

#include "SpectrumAnalysis.h"

class FFTBufferManager
{
public:
    FFTBufferManager(UInt32 inNumberFrames);
    ~FFTBufferManager();
```

I tried to change the compiler to LLVM GCC 4.2, but it gives a lot of other errors:

```
Expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'FFTBufferManager'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it's very likely you forgot a `;` in `SpectrumAnalysis.h`

Comment: I guess it works if you remove the includes? Try to correct those files before you start correcting this one.

Comment: SpectrumAnalysis.h is correct. AurioTouch project compiles and runs fine. But when I add its files to my project, then pop up a lot of errors.

Comment: it looks as the xcode does not understand that it's a c++ code.

Comment: What extension is the source file for FFTBufferManager? `cpp`, `c`, `m`, `mm` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27554/discussion-between-ajit-thala-and-lordpingvin)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To mix C++ and Objective-C you need to use the [.mm extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html). If, however, your class is only C++ (and only includes C/C++ headers) then you can use the normal `.cpp` extension.

> *.mm*
>  A source file with this extension can contain C++ code in addition to Objective-C and C code. This extension should
>   be used only if you actually refer to C++ classes or features from
>   your Objective-C code.

Comment: what about .h files, where c++ class get defined? to which extension it should be changed?

Comment: @peetonn .h is fine since they do not get compiled. You are also free to use .hh and .hpp.